Azure Pipelines - Can't find directory on Agent
I've got an Azure Pipeline that uses a Powershell task to install a module then runs another Powershell script which uses the module.
I've tried using command line to list the files on the Azure Agent as I have a variable in MyScript.ps1 which needs the install path but I can't find it on the Agent.
Can someone help me find the install directory on the Agent?
The install path is below on my local machine
$DataCompareExecutablePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Red Gate\SQL Data Compare 12\SQLDataCompare.exe"

When I use tree on the agent I can't see any install path
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: tree \

The following is my Pipeline
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Install-Module -Name SqlChangeAutomation -AllowClobber -Force -AcceptLicense
    
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: tree \

- pwsh: ./myscript.ps1
  displayName: 'Run my script'


Thanks,
Dan

Why you run tree command? What is the Error Message? Is it from PowerShell@2 task? Is Install-Module -Name SqlChangeAutomation works fine? Do you using self hosted agent?

Tree lists a lot of files but it appears as though installation directory is not listed.
Install-Module -Name SqlChangeAutomation
works fine.
I've been runining a Microsoft Hosted Ubuntu agent.
When I've developed the Powershell script it was on a Windows machine so i'm looking for the C/Program Files directory which doesn't exist on the Ubuntu agent.
